# Sql : Difference between two columns for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
PDO#         Item Code            To Issue   InStock    i want to see
63551     724S3607-109M02_01        1          60           59
63552     724S3607-109M02_01        1          60           58
63553     724S3607-109M02_01        2          60           56
63554     724S3607-109M02_01        7          60           49
```

where the data in the column i want to see, is 60-1(In stock-To Issue),59-1(i wnat to see - to issue),58-2(i wnat to see - to issue),56-7(i wnat to see - to issue) and so on.
Any help is appreciated .

Comment: is this for mysql or for sql-server ?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion i am working with microsoft sql server managment studio.

Comment: Then why the MySQL tag? BTW  managment studio is just a GUI client for SQL Server. The actual database engine is simply Microsoft SQL Server. Edit: Thanks for removing the unnecessary tag. Don't tag things that aren't relevant, it confuses people. A SQL Server version number would also be helpful, since some syntax isn't available on older versions.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL server are you using? 2008, 2012, ...?

Comment: What defines the order in which to process the i want to see column?   the PDO# earliest # being first?

Comment: The Pdo# earliest being first

Answer (score 2):

You can use query as below

```
Select *, YourOutputColumn = InStock - Sum([To Issue]) over(partition by [Item Code] order by [PDO#]) 
from yourtable
```